# I want to add django form with html specific input

Tags: django

```
<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"></div>
<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ></div>
```

I want to add {{ form.email }} and {{ form.password }} to the email and password field. This is the django default login view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your own custom login form using the Django Authentication back end.
This also includes defining cleaning the data within the form and managing post requests as well. A sample user registration form I had created. The same concept can be extended for your application.

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label='Email Address', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
    'class': 'form-control',
    'name': 'email',
            'id': 'email'
}))
password = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
    'class': 'form-control',
    'name': 'password',
            'id': 'password',
}))
password_1 = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Confirm password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
    'class': 'form-control',
    'name': 'password_1',
            'id': 'password_1',
}))
```